# sed from constant regex

Tags: regex, sed

I tried to remove the unwanted symbols

```
%H1256
*+E1111
  *;E2311
   +-'E3211
      {E4511
       DE4513
```

so I tried by using this command

```
sed 's/+E[0-9]/E/g
```

but it won't remove the blank spaces, and the digits need to be preserved.

expected:

```
H1256
E1111
E2311
E3211
E4511
E4513
```

EDIT

Special thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) my days have been saved by him

```
sed -n 's/.*\([A-Z][0-9]*\).*/\1/p' file or grep -oE '[A-Z][0-9]+' file
```

Comment: What are the "unwanted symbols"? What is the rule that you want to apply?

Comment: Maybe `sed -n 's/.*\([A-Z][0-9]*\).*/\1/p' file` or `grep -oE '[A-Z][0-9]+' file`? However, these will extract `E4511`, too, but it is missing from the expected results, why?

Comment: thanks a lot, it's really helping me, sorry for the typo, have been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use either `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*\([[:upper:]][[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

or `grep`:

```
grep -oE '[[:upper:]][[:digit:]]+' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Ml6O5Y)

Basically, the patterns match an uppercase letter (`[[:upper:]]`) followed with digits (`[[:digit:]]*` matches 0 or more digits in the POSIX BRE `sed` solution and `[[:digit:]]+` matches 1+ digits in an POSIX ERE `grep` solution).

While `sed` solution will extract a single value (last one) from each line, `grep` will extract all values it finds from all lines.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
sed -E 's/^[^[:alnum:]]+//' file
```

Or if it is only the last 5 characters you need

```
sed -E 's/.*(.{5})$/\1/' file
```